# jQuery TOOLS modal dialog linking issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I am using the [jQuery Tools library](http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/overlay/index.html) to display some modal dialogs in a Grails project. Whenever the 0th cell of any row in this table is clicked, a modal dialog pops showing the details about that row like this:
[image]
Now, once you're done clearing the flags as described in the photo, and you press `Save`, that row changes its dot in the 0th cell to green but then looses the ability to bring up the modal dialog in case you wish to see it again. Only this row gets affected by this issue, if the template is rendered again, the issue resolves itself. This is how the 0th cell gets its click functionality when it is first rendered in a GSP template:

```
<tr class = "datarow">
                              <td>
                                <g:if test="${record.overallStatus == 'red'}">
                                    <a class = "modalInput" rel = "#flagsSummary" style = "cursor:pointer">
                                        <g:img dir="images" file="circleRed.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                                    </a>
                                </g:if>
                                <g:if test="${record.overallStatus == 'yellow'}">
                                    <a class = "modalInput" rel = "#flagsSummary" style = "cursor:pointer">
                                        <g:img dir="images" file="circleYellow.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                                    </a>
                                </g:if>
                                <g:if test="${record.overallStatus == 'greenR'}">
                                    <a class = "modalInput" rel = "#flagsSummary" style = "cursor:pointer">
                                        <g:img dir="images" file="circleGreenHollow.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                                    </a>
                                </g:if>
                                <g:if test="${record.overallStatus == 'greenN'}">
                                    <a class = "modalInput" rel = "#flagsSummary" style = "cursor:pointer">
                                        <g:img dir="images" file="circleGreen.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                                    </a>
                                </g:if>
                              </td>
```

`flagsSummary` is the name of the div that pop's up as the modal dialog. So, you can see that each row's dot in the table is made into a link with it's `rel` attribute set up to pop the modal dialog div. Once you edit the record by clearing it's flags and then save it, I use the following Javascript to change the dot in the table to correspond to the record's new status:

```
$('#save').click(function () {
            var overAllStatus = localStorage.getItem('overAllStatus');
            localStorage.removeItem('overAllStatus');
            if (overAllStatus == 'red') {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleRed.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
            }
            else if (overAllStatus == 'yellow') {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleYellow.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
            }
            else if (overAllStatus == 'greenR') {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleGreenHollow.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
            }
            else if (overAllStatus == 'greenN') {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleGreen.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
            }
            comments = $('#comments').val();
            $("body").trigger(esc);
            $("#save1").trigger('click');
            redListSize = 0;
            yellowListSize = 0;
        });
```

You can see that I set the HTML identically to how it was before but it still looses the ability to bring up that modal dialog. The dot does change it's color but just looses the ability to pop up the modal dialog. Is there a way around this? Is this an issue with the jQuery TOOLS library? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like when you are refreshing/reloading the content the event handler that is attached to your 'red dot' isn't being bound. Without seeing your full code it's hard to say, but look for whatever is attaching the click event to the 'red dot'. E.g. `$(".some-selector").on("click", ...);` exists in the containing HTML page which isn't being called when the content is updated.

Comment: @Joshua Moore I think what takes care of attaching the click handler is the fact that when you declare the the 'rel' attribute and 'class=modalInput' of any button or link then the jQuery TOOLS library recognizes that as a launch point for a modal. So, I think there is some 'behind the scenes' Javascript that gets generated in which case how would I see that? That is also what is probably not happening when I render the inner HTML using JS.

Comment: Sounds like the library is looking at the DOM for matching elements when the library is included/loaded. When you change the DOM it's not picking up those changes (to be expected). You should look at the source code for the library to see how it's attaching the event listeners and if there is a way to tell it to refresh itself because of a change to the DOM or if there is a manual way you can attach the event listeners to the newly added/updated DOM elements. I have no doubt this is the issue you are having.

Comment: @Joshua Moore This might not even work but its a grand idea for a grasshopper like me. Instead of replacing the entire inner HTML can I somehow leave the link (the <a> element) alone and replace just the image nested inside it? That's all I really want anyway, if I can do this I need some help with the JS syntax. So, I would want to leave the <a> element as is since it has the 'wiring' to bring up the modal and just change the <img> or <g:img> nested inside it.